# XML Document is not valid - post request

Tags: python, xml, post, request

I have API that requires whitelisted IPs. I am trying to send a post request to it, which is in XML format.

The xsd is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name="VW_WCF_SF_VAL_QRY">
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="GAS_DAY" type="xs:date"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="LDZ">
     <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:length value="2"/>
      </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

from which, I generated an XML document as so (using an XSD -> XML converter)

```
data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VW_WCF_SF_VAL_QRY>
<GAS_DAY>2018-02-01</GAS_DAY>
</VW_WCF_SF_VAL_QRY>"""
```

I have tried passing the following post request

```
# header = {'Cookie': authentication_cookie}
r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=header)
```

But get the following error response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<errors xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://prod-ix.geminints.com:4445/gemini/api/schema/geminiapierror.xsd">
 <errInfo ID="1">
  <errCode>
   GEM_API_ERROR_0001
  </errCode>
  <errDesc>
   XML Document is not valid
  </errDesc>
 </errInfo>
</errors>
```

I am unsure as to what is causing this.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this `\` character:

```
</VW_WCF_SF_VAL_QRY\>"""
                   ^
```

Comment: good spot, but that was just a typo i made when copying and pasting to SO, sorry. Still getting the same error :/. The best guess as to what the problem is, is the way im sending the xml data. Should it just be a string, or base encoded another way?

Comment: You're right, I will close this. Was hoping it was something obvious, was just clutching as straws I guess.

Comment: You might find that in the course of creating a MCVE, you'll discover the issue yourself.

Comment: I have in fact gotten to that stage, and the problem is with how I'm uploading the XML. For the queries that don't need the xml data, it works perfectly.
I have tried `INPUT=<xml goes here>` or 
`INPUT="<xml goes here>"` or
`<xml goes here>` (no INPUT=)
and still no luck

Comment: Another idea from [another context](https://www.gasgovernance.co.uk/sites/default/files/ggf/APIUsageGuidelinesv320050929.pdf) but related to your `errCode`: *Note: When invoking functional APIs you must not set a value of “text/xml” for the
Content-Type header key. This can result in GEM_API_ERROR_0001 (“XML
document is not valid”) messages returned for perfectly valid XML.*

Comment: That's the API I am trying to access, and the only header I am using is Cookie (and no Content-Type). Thanks for trying though :). Regarding: "As a URL parameter? Have you tried POSTing it in the request body? – kjhughes 15 hours ago". Isn't setting data=data posting it as the request body?, i.e. `data = "INPUT=<xml goes here>"`

Comment: Yes, I've deleted that comment, but it's strange to see `INPUT=` in the request body.

Comment: I agree, definitely the weirdest API i've come across to date.